# Whether the following subset in the space of function is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, banach-spaces, frechet-derivative

I am facing a problem as the following: Suppose $\mathcal{H}$ is a Hilbert space with inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and its induced norm $|\cdot|$. Consider the space of functions $(x,t)\in\mathcal{H}\times[0,T]\mapsto\lambda(x,t)\in\mathcal{H}$ equipped with the norm
\begin{align*}
\|\lambda\| := \sup_{x\in\mathcal{H},t\in[0,T]}\frac{|\lambda(x,t)|}{|x|},
\end{align*}
this is a Banach space. However, consider the set of function such that
\begin{align*}
\|\lambda\|\leq A_1,\,\,\,\|D_x\lambda(x,t)\|_{\text{linear operator}}\leq A_2,
\end{align*}
where $D_x$ is in Frechet sense, and the norm corresponding is the operator norm for linear operators. Is this set closed?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I suggest solving it for $\cal H = \Bbb R$ first, Then try to apply what you learn to the broader situation.